# Title attribute causes stylesheet stops working

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I'm currently experimenting with CSS Object Model and try to understand how do all properties and methods of `StyleSheet`, `CSSStyleSheet`, `CSSRule` and all objects of this sort work. I can't figure out why, if I add `title` attribute for my `<link rel="stylesheet">` elements results in 'switching off' the particular stylesheet while the `disabled` property is still set to `false` for all stylesheets?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css" title="a"/>  <!--this works-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="b.css" title="b"/>  <!--this does not work-->
```

Comment: Could you please share you CSS linked to these two elements ?

Comment: it does not matter, it can be anything, lets say `body{background-color:#33aaff;}` for the first stylesheet and `body{color:red;}` for the second one.

Comment: Well it does matter if you forgot an element in your css or if you are calling changes based on title tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MDN - [Correctly Using Titles With External Stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Correctly_Using_Titles_With_External_Stylesheets)

> ... A preferred stylesheet, on the other hand, is one that has a value of stylesheet supplied for the `rel` attribute, and any value at all for the `title` attribute. Here are two examples:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="Basic styles" href="basic.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="Fish and boats" href="ocean.css" />
```

> According to the HTML 4.01 specification, only one of the preferred stylesheets can be used at a time. Therefore, given the above example, only one of the two preferred stylesheets will be applied to the document. The specification does not supply a procedure to decide which one should be used, so user agents are free to make whatever choice they like...

Comment: A very handy and very underrated feature.